# reference .net6 dll on .net framework 4.8 project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.8

I have an class library targetting the .Net Framework 4.8.

I'm trying to add a reference to the [PnP Framework](https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework) which is "a .NET Standard 2.0 / .NET 5.0 / .NET 6.0 library".

It seems to be causing a conflict with the System.Runtime and System.Runtime.Interopservices.

I tried adding some references but I can't seem to make this work.

Is this at all possible? Maybe through some sort of conditional loading of these assemblies...

[image]

Comment: Without the *.csproj file, it is hard to get an idea of what is goin gon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was going on.

From what I understand, the [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0) is a specification that aims at providing compatibility, in particular between frameworks.

My project uses the .Net Framework 4.8 (latest) and I was trying to add a reference to a .NET5/6 dll, when I should have been adding the .NET Standard 2.0 dll, which works in the .Net Framework (4.8).

After adding the right dll (netstandard 2.0) the project could build and run.
There were a number of issues after related to dependencies and I ended up installing the pnp package through the "Manage Nuget Packages" option under "Project" instead of referencing the individual dll.

Just adding this in case it helps someone in the future.

Related:
[Using CSOM for .NET Standard instead of CSOM for .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard)